# Webpack using flags to run different script

Tags: webpack, configuration, localization, package.json, flags

I have a few scripts in my package.json for location based scripts (this is the Canadian version).

```
"dev-ca": "npm run development-ca",
"development-ca": "cross-env process.env.location=us NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
```

this works ok but I have to run

```
npm run dev-ca
```

I would rather run

```
npm run dev --ca
```

Is this possible? I still want to run my standard npm run dev for my local (UK) site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass flags to an npm script (as opposed to `npm run` itself) pass them after a final `--`, like so:

```
npm run dev -- --ca
```

Then a crude solution to pick the flag up in your build would be:

```
// somewhere in your config file
const argv = process.argv.join('');
let location = 'uk'; // default to UK
for (const flag of ['ca', /* other locations... */]) {
  if (argv.includes(`--${flag}`)) {
    location = flag;
  }
}
```

An improvement on this would be to use a flag parser, e.g. [minimist](https://github.com/substack/minimist), especially if you are passing more than one flag.